# How to format string into date using Java

Tags: java

I need to format a string into date using java.
My String is "15th July, 2014"
I need to convert it into date format like "15-07-2014"

Can anyone help me regarding that.

Comment: I tried the following code-----But it showing error "Unparseable date: "15th July,2014"                                                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  
  String dateStr = "15th July, 2014";

  Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
  System.out.println(date);
  System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

Comment: Are your monthes names written entirely ? Or is there a limit such as "Novemb" for "November" for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample

```
    String dateString = "15th July, 2014";
    dateString= dateString.replace("th", "").replace("nd", "").replace("rd", "").replace("st", "");

    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
    Date dt = formatter1.parse(dateString);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(formatter2.format(dt));
```

Read the javadoc on SimpleDateFormat for various options
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It doesn't help to parse the date from the questioner's string

Comment: I didn't notice that you had String to begin with. I updated the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat to parse the String as a java.util.Date object;
then use another SimpleDataFormat to format the date object to any format you need.

Refer to JavaDoc for details (How to set the dateformat string)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to define a SimpleDateFormat and use the parse method.

You can define almost any date pattern you want, just take a look on the pattern definition listed on javadocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Beware SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.